# How to move an EXE file to Wine's fake C: drive

Tags: 12.04, wine, drive, executable

can anyone tell me how I can move a .exe file to Wine's fake C: drive? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wine folder is hidden by default. To access it, open your Home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This will show all the hidden folders. Open `.wine` and go to the `drive_c` folder. Move the .exe there.

If the .exe file is from a Windows partition, you must first mount the partition to be able to access the files.

Comment: Haha no problem. Happy programming! :D

Comment: You don't have to move the .exe file in Wine's C:\ directory in order to run it. You can right click on the executable and choose open with wine. You can also set the default program that open's .exe files to be wine so with double clicking on them the work can be done. You do that by right clicking on a .exe file select properties and in open with tab you select wine and set it as default